# Using Thymeleaf if username is not avilable in session its gives error

Tags: thymeleaf

If the session contains username attribute it will display the value  if the attribute username is not in session object. it will give error org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression:

How to solve the error or get null if username doesnot exist in session

```
 <span>Hello</span>
 <span th:text="${session.username}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just evaluate your username before displaying it:

```
<span th:text="${session.username == null} ?: ''" />
```

Comment: You can use the elvis operator, in cases like this: `<span th:text="${session.username} ?: ''" />` -- http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#default-expressions-elvis-operator